# How to show/hide comment using jquery while operate with DOM

Tags: jquery

I would like to thanks to this post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727635/jquery-show-all-comments-click-hide-at-success) it is actually working but only when html document written directly.
But it doesn't work while apply the same thing in document that created by jquery. can you please advise how to solve this?

my code is

```
<script>
var toggle = false;
$(function() {
    $('a.comments').click(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.toggleComments').toggle(1000,function() {
            if(!toggle) {
                $this.text('Hide Comments');
                toggle = !toggle;
            }else {
                $this.text('Show Comments');
                toggle = !toggle;
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}); 

var html;
$(document).ready(function()
{
html='<a href="#" class="comments">Show Comments</a><br /><div class="toggleComments">This is #comment1 <br />This is #comment2 <br /></div>';

$("#start").append(html);

}); 
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="start"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your event handler applied to dynamically created elements, you need the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function :

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a.comments', function(e) {
```

The provided function will be called on click even on elements added to the DOM in the future.

Comment: Hi dystroy, This is working for me. thanks for you great help.

Comment: Hi dystroy, do you know how to do this kind of thing in case I have 10 comments groups, do to do show/hide independently without having 10 Jquery scripts.

Comment: It's sure you can do this without 10 scripts but your question isn't clear to me. What's a "comment group" ? What prevents you to use `$(this)` inside the callback function ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to bind an event to an element before it exists. Just rearrange the code a little bit so the the element exists when you bind a click event to it. You can see it working on this [jsFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/peterolson/SAE9A/). You might want to rethink your logic a little bit since the text doesn't quite have the behavior you would expect.

```
var html;
$(document).ready(function() {
    html = '<a href="#" class="comments">Show Comments</a><br /><div class="toggleComments">This is #comment1 <br />This is #comment2 <br /></div>';

    $("#start").append(html);
    var toggle = false;
    $('a.comments').click(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.toggleComments').toggle(1000, function() {
            if (toggle) {
                $this.text('Hide Comments');
            } else {
                $this.text('Show Comments');
            }
            toggle = !toggle;
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

You can also use the `on` function to automatically bind to dynamically added elements. All you have to do is change `$("a.comments").click(function() {})` to `$(document).on('click', 'a.comments', function() {})`.

Answer (score 0):

Use .live to solve this something like this

```
$('a.comments').live('click',function(){
 //do your job here
});
```

Comment: You can use it if you are not using jquery 1.7 however yes what dystroy has suggested is the preferred approach as of now

Comment: Read the link I gave. "Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Comment: Thanks to Alice and dystroy, that new to me.